# How to hyperlink a cell in google spreadsheets to an image in a folder on google drive?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a google spreadsheet with a column named photo. In that column are image names (ex: "123") which match up to images in a separate google drive folder (ex: "IMG_123.jpg").  Currently, in order to view an image I have to open up the google drive folder and search for the image manually.

I would like to do something like this, if A1 is the cell with contents "123":

```
"=HYPERLINK('https://drive.google.com/drive/foldername/IMG_"&A1&".jpg',"&A1&");"
```

If this is even possible, what should the url be to reference a specific image?

**UPDATE**

Now I've created a google script function that works! But it only seems to work on the first active cell in a range:

```
function getImageLinks() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("my_folder_id_here");
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();

  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
      var imgName = range.getCell(i,j).getValue();
      while (contents.hasNext()) {
        var file = contents.next();
        var fileName = file.getName();

        if(fileName.search(imgName) >= 0){
          range.getCell(i,j).setFormula("=HYPERLINK(\""+file.getUrl()+"\",\""+imgName+"\")");
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it'll quite work that way. You'll notice if you go to that particular folder that the URL does not reference the folder name. It references a particular ID string. The same goes for files.

There are [ways to do that with Google Script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86081/insert-image-from-google-drive-into-google-sheets/86103#86103).

```
function getImageLinks() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("YOUR_FOLDERID");
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log('number of rows = ' + numRows);

  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {

      var imgName = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue(); //adjust number to reflect column of value
      while (contents.hasNext()) {
        var file = contents.next();
        var fileName = file.getName();

        if(fileName.search(imgName) >= 0){
          sheet.getRange(i,1).setFormula("=HYPERLINK(\""+file.getUrl()+"\",\""+imgName+"\")"); //adjust number for getRange to reflect column
          break;

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Should be the large chunk of random text in the URL when you're in that folder.

Comment: You're too quick. I tried to delete that comment because I saw you put the answer within the code you linked too haha. Thanks. I'm going to try something similar out

Comment: I updated my question with a variation on your code, if you could help with the final issue I would like to accept your answer

Comment: Can you clarify a bit on the source spreadsheet? Are all the file names in column A? Trying to figure out why you're counting columns as well as rows. Any reason not to just make the script list all the files in the folder by itself?

Comment: Yeah so I'm counting the rows and columns in order to get the contents of the next cell in the loop `range.getCell(i,j).getValue()`. Then I can test if that text is in any of the image names in that folder. The file names are technically in column O but I just want to select a small portion to run the code.  I don't just list all the files because I don't need them all, I only need to link to the corresponding image according to image name in column O.  If there's a better way please let me know!

Comment: I edited the response. I think it's pretty close to what you want. Just change the numbers in the getRange to reflect O instead of A.

Comment: This works! I just had to make one change... I moved the `folder` and `contents` variable declarations to inside of the `for loop` because it was reaching the end of the folder and not starting from the beginning again for the next item.  I suggest you update your code accordingly for others to see.